# Core Data without Master Detail Template

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I want to create an iphone application which uses Core Data.
As i understood, only master-detail application template gives me an option to use Core Data. But it creates table view.

What i want to use is view controller not table view controller.
I couldnt use core data with single view application template..

Which way should I follow to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: just delete the unwanted files from the bundle, add the new `UIViewController` to your bundle and, finally, modify the `AppDelegate.m` file for loading the your new `UIViewController` and _violá_, it is done. :) or... you could create a new application with `CoreData` and you copy the relevant parts of `CoreData` from the `AppDelegate.m` and `AppDelegate.h` into your other project without `CoreData` with the desired `UIViewController`, add the `CoreData` file, and _violá_, you`ve done it again. :)

Comment: As I have already implemented many things, your first option would be great if I can manage to do that. I am not sure What should i change in Appdelegate.m?Thanks

Comment: add these methods to you `AppDelegate.m` file: `-saveContext`, `-managedObjectContext`, `-managedObjectModel` and `persistentStoreCoordinator` and, please make sure this file has the `-applicationDocumentsDirectory` method. add the following `readonly` properties to your `AppDelegate.h` file for the `NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSManagedObjectModel`, `NSManagedObjectModel` and the `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`, and make sure your application linked the `CoreData.framework` as well.

Comment: but it seems someone can give more detailed answer below. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should realize that CoreData is a framework that is not bound to any UIKit components like UITableView. You can freely use it in any sort of an application. All you have to do is to create your singleton class that manages CoreData operations and add CoreData.framework to your project.

Here is my DataAccessLayer template:

DataAccessLayer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface DataAccessLayer : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator;

+ (DataAccessLayer *)sharedInstance;
- (void)saveContext;

@end
```

DataAccessLayer.m

```
#import "DataAccessLayer.h"
@interface DataAccessLayer ()
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end

@implementation DataAccessLayer
@synthesize storeCoordinator;
@synthesize managedObjectModel;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

+ (DataAccessLayer *)sharedInstance {
  __strong static DataAccessLayer *sharedInstance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[DataAccessLayer alloc] init];
    sharedInstance.storeCoordinator = [sharedInstance persistentStoreCoordinator];
    sharedInstance.managedObjectContext = [sharedInstance managedObjectContext];
  });
  return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data

- (void)saveContext {
  @synchronized(self) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
      if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
      {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.userInfo);
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                        message:@"Something has gone terribly wrong! You need to reinstall the app in order for it to work properly."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close."
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
      } 
    }
  }
}

#pragma mark Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
  if (managedObjectContext != nil)
  {
    return managedObjectContext;
  }

  if (storeCoordinator != nil)
  {
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:storeCoordinator];
  }
  return managedObjectContext;
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
  if (managedObjectModel != nil)
  {
    return managedObjectModel;
  }
  NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
  managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
  return managedObjectModel;
}

/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
  if (storeCoordinator != nil)
  {
    return storeCoordinator;
  }

  NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"words_db.sqlite"];

  NSError *error = nil;
  storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
  if (![storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
  {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

     Typical reasons for an error here include:
     * The persistent store is not accessible;
     * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


     If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

     If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
     * Simply deleting the existing store:
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

     * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

     Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                    message:@"Something has gone terribly wrong! You need to reinstall the app in order for it to work properly."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close."
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
  }    

  return storeCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark Application's Documents directory

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
  return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}


@end
```

You will also have to create an .xcdatamodeld file in order to create your Data Model objects.  And replace the name here with appropriate

```
  NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

Comment: I did as you said. Then copied all my existing code to the newly created app. There is no build error. But when I run it i get runtime error saying that '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'UserData'' UserData is my entity name in my core data.. Do you have any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: What i was doing in my previous app was creating managedobjectcontext in the same class so i was using NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]; but now i guess we are creating it in datalayeraccess class, so instead if self managedobjectcontext should i use something else?

Comment: Finally did it. Thank you for the guide!!